# Eclipse Autocomplete shows 'Problems During Content Assist' popups

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Lately I've been getting these 2 strange error messages in Eclipse. These happen the first time i press `.` , such as in `MyClass.myMethod()`, pressing the `.` causes these messages to popup. They show up only the first time after Eclipse is started and don't show up again until next restart.

**First error:**

[image]

**Second error:**

[image]

These might be related to some new updates that I installed on Eclipse. Any ideas how to get rid of them?

Comment: Which updates did you install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Eclipse errors should be logged, so see if you can see them in the *Error Log* view. Open it either by pressing **Ctrl+Shift+Q, L** or using the menu **Window > Show View > Error Log**.

As Yuval A [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693225/weird-error-in-eclipse-autocomplete/693233#693233), either find the existing bug (and read any workarounds) or report a new one in [bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=content%2Bassist) - you'll be helping out Eclipse developers and users (not to mention yourself) by reporting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I get those as well from time to time. Bug in Eclipse, I believe.

Check out the [content assist bug list](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=content+assist). If nothing there is relevant to your specific situation you can open a bug.

Comment: Its been happening consistently now, don't seem to be going away